# How to implement the "cache then network" strategy with workbox-cli?

Tags: workbox

How to implement the "[cache then network](https://web.dev/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network)" strategy with [workbox-cli](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli)?

I need up to date content without leaving the website and revisiting it again (which is the behavior with the "stale while revalidate" strategy, which is the one used in workbox-cli if I understood well).

And I need workbox-cli because not only it handles the writing of the service worker file, but above all it takes care of the cache renaming after each build, which would be a hassle to rename manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways of using `workbox-cli`, depending on your configuration.

Some of this boils down to the difference between precaching and runtime caching. There's some background on that distinction in [this blog post](https://jeffy.info/2021/07/26/precaching-vs-runtime-caching.html).

If you're using `workbox-cli` to precache all of your content, and you want to automatically reload your web app whenever there's an update detected to any of the precached content, you could follow the example in this "[Offer a page reload for users](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users)" recipe, but call `window.location.reload()` unconditionally, instead of waiting for the user to confirm that they want to update.

Comment: Thank you Jeff! Are there no ways to update the page without a reload? I saw some apps using Workbox and the update is just a subtle blink of the page, like there is no reloading (ex: https://excalidraw.com/) : maybe some React/SPA magic instead of a native JS reload?

Comment: Once the new precached assets are available, based on the presence of the `waiting` service worker, you could re-run whatever client-side rendering logic you have and it will pick up the new assets (assuming they have the same URL). Those implementation details will vary a lot depending on, e.g., your client-side freamework.